transform transition image 'jumping' at start and end of animation
So I have a div that I want to expand (along with all elements it contains) when hovered over.. it's mostly working except at the start and end of the animation the background image 'jumps' to an odd position for ~0.1s. I've seen this is an issue posted before on stack overflow but the solutions provided don't seem to fit my issue.


.index {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.services-back-image {
  z-index: -2;
  transform-origin: 40% 0%;
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.services-home {
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.services-home:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
<div class="services-home p-5">
  <img class="services-back-image" src="/SVG/Asset 8.svg" alt="oops">
  <br>
  <h1 class="px-4 pt-4">Our Services</h1>
  <p class="px-4" style="color: darkslategray;">Click to Learn More!</p>
</div>



I know it's a bit of a mess right now but what's the main thing I'm doing wrong?
Video example: https://youtu.be/cr_dllsi41U
Thanks in advance :)

It would be helpful if you could make your code into a runnable snippet (use <> in the editor) and make sure there's an image we can use. I am a bit confused about why you want the image to scale differently from everything else - what effect are you looking for (in the text you say 'expand (along with all elements it contains)' but the img seems to be different.

Not sure if this is a fully appropriate reproduction of the problem, https://jsfiddle.net/qc0toaex/1/ - but the effect appears to have to do with the fact that you just positioned the image absolute, but without using the container as the reference point. The viewport is getting scrollbars, due to how you are scaling the .services-home - and that in turn then changes the position of the image. Un-comment the /*position: relative;*/ I put on that element there, and you'll see the difference.

@C3roe Thanks! That's stopped the jittering. :)

@AHaworth sorry for the confusion, I didn't mean to scale the image differently, that was a bad copy paste by me
